# Custom component not getting rendered properly on this basic ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a very basic `ReactJS` app which uses `Redux` which contains the following components:

```
PanelMaterialSize > Select
```

**/src/controls/PanelMaterialSize/PanelMaterialSize.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './PanelMaterialSize.scss';
import Select from '../Select/Select';
import { setThemeList } from '../../store/AppConfig/actions';

class PanelMaterialSize extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.n = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      let themeList = [
        { value: this.n, text: 'Option ' + this.n },
        { value: this.n + 1, text: 'Option ' + (this.n + 1) },
        { value: this.n + 2, text: 'Option ' + (this.n + 2) },
      ];
      this.props.setThemeList(themeList);
      this.n += 3;
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="partial-designer-panel-material-size">
        <div>
          <div className="label-input">
            <div className="label">MATERIAL</div>
            <div className="input">
              <Select data={this.props.themeList} style={{ width: '100%' }} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (appState) => {
  return {
    themeList: appState.appConfig.themeList,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setThemeList: (themeList) => dispatch(setThemeList(themeList)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PanelMaterialSize);
```

In my opinion the `Redux` logic is fine because I have tested by doing couple of things.

**My problem is** that when the `render(...)` method of: `PanelMaterialSize` gets called, the component: `Select` doesn't get rendered with the new data (which changes every one second).

Here you have a `Codesandbox.io` you can play with (preferable use `Chrome`):

https://codesandbox.io/s/03mj405zzv

Any idea on how to get its content changed properly?

If possible, please, provide back a new `Codesandbox.io` with your solution, forked from the previous one.

Thanks!

Comment: Your demo link is missing.

Comment: I just used your playground. I can see the select box rendering values. Can you elaborate your problem again?

Comment: by the way, just updated the code preview with small changes

Comment: @AshishKirodian, the values should change every one second but they don't do it

Comment: then change the key value for options from the index to some other unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here in your select component.
you are passing initially empty array and checking your component with this.state.data props, next time reducer change your this.state.data will not update the data. because you initialize in constructor. constructor only invoke once when component mount.

[SOLVED DEMO LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj7m3l49xq)

The Problem is in your select render method:

```
  render() {
    let data = this.state[this.name];
    return (
      <div className="control-select" {...this.controlProps}>
        <div className="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--grey">
          <select className="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--grey">
             //change data with this.props.data
            {this.props.data.length > 0 &&
              this.props.data.map((elem, index) => {
                return (
                  <option value={elem.value} key={index}>
                    {elem.text}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you please provide the Codesandbox.io forked from mine? (just in case refresh this page because I changed the link some minutes ago). Thanks!

Comment: just checked the demo link you provided above, but the options on the select don't change every one second

Comment: wait a min... i am changing

Comment: @davidesp did you get it?