# Cannot propagate custom Select value to its parent component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I have a basic `ReactJS` app which contains a custom `Select` which populates after 2 seconds.

**./src/controls/Select/Select.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Select.scss';

class Select extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let { name, value, data, className, onChange, onFocus, onBlur, ...controlProps } = this.props;
    this.name = name;
    this.onChange = onChange || ((e) => { });
    this.onFocus = onFocus || ((e) => { });
    this.onBlur = onBlur || ((e) => { });
    this.controlProps = controlProps;
    this.state = {
      [name]: value,
      className,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleChange({ target: this.refs.select });
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    let name = target.name;
    let value = target.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
    this.onChange(e);
  };

  render() {
    let data = this.props.data || [];
    return (
      <div className="control-select" {...this.controlProps}>
        <div className="custom-dropdown custom-dropdown--grey">
          <select
            ref="select"
            name={this.name}
            className="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--grey"
            value={this.state[this.name]}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {
              data.map((elem, index) => {
                return <option value={elem.value} key={index}>{elem.text}</option>
              })
            }
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Select;
```

Also I have the main `App`:

**./src/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Select from './controls/Select/Select';
import './styles.scss';

export default class Lab extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: '',
      options: [],
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        options: [
          { "value": "option_01", "text": "Option 01" },
          { "value": "option_02", "text": "Option 02" },
          { "value": "option_03", "text": "Option 03" },
          { "value": "option_04", "text": "Option 04" },
          { "value": "option_05", "text": "Option 05" },
        ],
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    let name = target.name;
    let value = target.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
        <div style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #ddd', margin: '20px 0 10px 0' }}>
          The value on the select box should appear on the yellow box automatically.
        </div>
                {/* BEGIN OF WORKING AREA */}
        <table style={{ display: 'inline-block', margin: '0 0 10px', border: 'none' }}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style={{ width: '218px', border: 'none' }}>
                <Select
                  name="selection"
                  value={this.state.selection}
                  data={ this.state.options.map(elem => { return { value: elem.value, text: elem.text }; }) }
                  style={{ width: '100%' }}
                  onChange={ this.handleChange }
                />
              </td>
              <td style={{ width: '100px', border: 'none', color: '#b00', backgroundColor: '#ffa', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '14px' }}>
                <span>{this.state.selection}</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {/* END OF WORKING AREA */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Lab />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

**What I need is** that just after the custom `Select` populates, it propagates its value to the parent component `state`. Right now, when it gets populated it doesn't do that (you can check this with the empty yellow box). In the other hand, if you change the option on that `Select` then its value gets propagated successfully.

Here you have its `Codesandbox.io` you can play with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/73z220z11q

If possible, please, provide back a forked `Codesandbox.io` with your solution.

This is what I want to happen:

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

Here you have the real code I'm concerned about:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xl6zxz0v84

If the user manually select an option on the `Select`, then that value is set properly as `selectedTheme` (inside App state). That part is fine.

**What I want is** if the user doesn't manually select anything, then the value showed on the select should be set as `selectedTheme`. Currently is set to nothing (if user doesn't interact).

You can check the value of `selectedTheme` by clicking the `Submit` button.

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot see anything on the above link , but can you explain you want the selected value in parent component?

Comment: @KOTIOS just added an explaining image to my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with how you are calling `handleChange` directly from the `componentDidMount` of your custom select.. **At that time, your `target` doesn't really have the `value` cause you are setting the options based on Redux state.**

To solve that, you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` in your component where you are getting the options from `Redux` and change the `state.selection` manually when you get updates. Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.options.length !== nextProps.options.length) {
    this.setState({ selection: nextProps.options[0].value });
  }
}
```

Here's [forked+updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjlwzpmwqz)

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for. I want the `Select` to be rendered from the beginning. On top of that, the list can change at anytime. Thanks, though.

Comment: @davidesp in that case, the best way would be to have `componentWillReceiveProps` and change `this.state.selection` as and when the options change

Comment: that's a bit tricky for me because there are multiple classes on the same file. Would it be possible for you to do that specific change on the new `Codesandbox.io` I provided under **[UPDATE]**? Thanks! https://codesandbox.io/s/xl6zxz0v84

Answer (score 0):

hi the mistake is select element only set selection when onChange function is triggered.

if you want, at the time population you need to set in manually or set default value in selection state.

```
 //set the selection default state at the time of setting options in constructor.
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection: "",
      options: []
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          options: [
            { value: "option_01", text: "Option 01" },
            { value: "option_02", text: "Option 02" },
            { value: "option_03", text: "Option 03" },
            { value: "option_04", text: "Option 04" },
            { value: "option_05", text: "Option 05" }
          ]
        },
        () => this.setState({ selection: this.state.options[0].value })
      );
    }, 2000);
  }
```

[Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/j37oxx99qy)

Comment: @davidesp did you get it?

Comment: that was a good try but unfortunately that approach doesn't work for me. This is a simplification of a bigger problem using `Redux`. The `Select` gets populated via `Redux` using `mapStateToProps(...), etc.` similar to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821440/custom-component-not-getting-rendered-properly-on-this-basic-reactjs-app. Then I need something that triggers the component state change coming from the `Select` instead of: `this.setState(...)`. Any idea about another approach? Thanks!

Comment: I just added an update to my initial post where I link to the real example I'm concerned about: https://codesandbox.io/s/xl6zxz0v84. Please read the text above under: **[UPDATE]**. Thanks!